# What is the difference between CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelbuffer) and CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelbuffer, 0)?

Tags: ios, swift, yuv, cvpixelbuffer

Is there any difference between `CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelbuffer)` and `CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelbuffer, 0)` ,  `CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelbuffer)` and `CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelbuffer, 0)` .

I search wiki, it says:

```
As with most Y′UV formats, there are as many Y′ values as there are pixels.
```

It does not says y's value is equal image width for all formats.

So if

```
CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelbuffer) == CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelbuffer, 0)
```

and

```
CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelbuffer) == CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelbuffer, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all pixel buffers are planar (that is, contain multiple data planes as is the case for YUV buffers). Check [`CVPixelBufferIsPlanar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456805-cvpixelbufferisplanar) to see if yours is before deciding which function to query width/height with. (Of course, you can safely skip that check if you’re getting buffers from a source that’s always planar.)

The docs for [`CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456830-cvpixelbuffergetwidthofplane) note that it always returns zero when passed a non-planar buffer. In that case, the return value (for plane 0) is not expected to equal that of [`CVPixelBufferGetWidth`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1457241-cvpixelbuffergetwidth).

Comment: If the pixel buffer is planar, is `CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelbuffer) == CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelbuffer, 0)` in iOS platform